# How to setup Blogger API on Android

Tags: java, android, google-api, blogger, google-api-java-client

I want to make an app which will use Google's Blogger API V3. But I've got stuck at the setup part. I've made an API key on developer console. I've read trough several tutorials and samples and everywhere they use this object

```
Blogger
```

For example here:
[Blogger example](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/get)

I downloaded the Java client library, copied to my application's libs folder, added to the build path, but still can't use this Blogger object.
[Java client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/blogger/v3)

Where can I get the library that contains the Blogger object?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you want to do with the Blogger API. If you want to access non-public data you should use Oauth2.0 to authenticate so for that I suggest reading this 
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth#retrieve_the_account_name

Then you will probably want to send request to your API (POST,GET, DELETE or others) in order to perform actions such as post on your blog, retrieve comments or posts from your blog.
I have found this link very usefull 
http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/